# Creating JSON from CSV with Formatting

Tags: python, json

I am looking to build the following structure.  I have already written the code to parse my csv.  But now I am looking to format the structure of the csv.  I want to group like testInfo and finInfo within area_id or main node for each element.

Example Json:

```
    [
    {
        "area_id": "13", 
        "area_name": "Joanne Smith", 
        "test_diff": "27%", 
        "test_id": "1239", 
        "test_pull": "119", 
        "test_name": "Finals 2019",
        "fin_id" : "019",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2019"
    }, 
    {
        "area_id": "12", 
        "area_name": "Joe Turner", 
        "test_diff": "7%", 
        "test_id": "1233", 
        "test_pull": "149", 
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "000",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    }, 
    {
        "area_id": "12", 
        "area_name": "Joe Turner", 
        "test_diff": "7%", 
        "test_id": "1234", 
        "test_pull": "150", 
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "001",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    }, 
    {
        "area_id": "12", 
        "area_name": "Joe Turner", 
        "test_diff": "7%", 
        "test_id": "1234", 
        "test_pull": "150", 
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "003",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    }
]
```

end result I am looking for is

```
[{"areaid":"12","areaname":"Joe Turner","testInfo":[{"testid":"1233","testname":"Finals 2020"},{"testid":"1234","testname":"Finals 2020"},{"testid":"1234","testname":"Finals 2020"}],"finInfo":[{"finid":"000","finname":"Results Fin 2020"},{"finid":"001","finname":"Results Fin 2020"},{"finid":"003","finname":"Results Fin 2020"}]},{"areaid":"13","areaname":"Joanne Smith","testInfo":[{"testid":"1239","testname":"Finals 2019"}],"finInfo":[{"finid":"019","finname":"Results Fin 2019"}]}]
```

Desired Output

```
[ { "areaid":"12", "areaname":"Joe Turner", "testInfo":[ { "testid":"1233", "testname":"Finals 2020", "finInfo":[ { "finid":"000", "finname":"Results Fin 2020" } ] }, { "testid":"1234", "testname":"Finals 2020", "finInfo":[ { "finid":"001", "finname":"Results Fin 2020" }, { "finid":"003", "finname":"Results Fin 2020" } ] } ] }, { "areaid":"13", "areaname":"Joanne Smith", "testInfo":[ { "testid":"1239", "testname":"Finals 2019", "finInfo":[ { "finid":"019", "finname":"Results Fin 2019" } ] } ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what should be the output format, but you can try to use this code sample and replace `print` call with your implementation.

from collections import defaultdict

```
arr = [
    {
        "area_id": "13",
        "area_name": "Joanne Smith",
        "test_diff": "27%",
        "test_id": "1239",
        "test_pull": "119",
        "test_name": "Finals 2019",
        "fin_id" : "019",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2019"
    },
    {
        "area_id": "12",
        "area_name": "Joe Turner",
        "test_diff": "7%",
        "test_id": "1233",
        "test_pull": "149",
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "000",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    },
    {
        "area_id": "12",
        "area_name": "Joe Turner",
        "test_diff": "7%",
        "test_id": "1234",
        "test_pull": "150",
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "001",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    },
    {
        "area_id": "12",
        "area_name": "Joe Turner",
        "test_diff": "7%",
        "test_id": "1234",
        "test_pull": "150",
        "test_name": "Finals 2020",
        "fin_id" : "003",
        "fin_name" : "Results Fin 2020"
    }
]

formatted_data = defaultdict(lambda: {
    'testinfo': [],
    'fininfo': []
})

for item in arr:
    area_id = item['area_id']
    area_name = item['area_name']
    area_data = formatted_data[(area_id, area_name)]
    area_data['testinfo'].append({
        'testid': item['test_id'],
        'testname': item['test_name']
    })
    area_data['fininfo'].append({
        'finid': item['fin_id'],
        'finname': item['fin_name']
    })

result = []
for (area_id, area_name), item_data in formatted_data.items():
    result_item = {}
    result_item['areaid'] = area_id
    result_item['areaname'] = area_name
    result_item['testInfo'] = []
    for testinfo in item_data['testinfo']:
        result_item['testInfo'].append(testinfo)
    result_item['finInfo'] = []
    for fininfo in item_data['fininfo']:
        result_item['finInfo'].append(fininfo)

    result.append(result_item)

print(result)
```

Desired Output

[
    {
       "areaid":"12",
       "areaname":"Joe Turner",
       "testInfo":[
          {
             "testid":"1233",
             "testname":"Finals 2020",
             "finInfo":[
                {
                   "finid":"000",
                   "finname":"Results Fin 2020"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "testid":"1234",
             "testname":"Finals 2020",
             "finInfo":[
                {
                   "finid":"001",
                   "finname":"Results Fin 2020"
                },
                {
                   "finid":"003",
                   "finname":"Results Fin 2020"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "areaid":"13",
       "areaname":"Joanne Smith",
       "testInfo":[
          {
             "testid":"1239",
             "testname":"Finals 2019",
             "finInfo":[
                {
                   "finid":"019",
                   "finname":"Results Fin 2019"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ]

Comment: this is close, I updated the post with desired output based on the solution you submitted.  Please let me know if this achievable.

Comment: so last question.  Looking at the output I think I may have confused the results.  the finInfo should be a subset of the testInfo.  this way if there are multiple testid's they would only show one and that testid could have multiple finid's or info under it.  Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @kingjtiv could you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: Added to your solution.

Comment: Updated to the main as well.  Thank you

Comment: wondering if you had any suggestion to achieve the new desired outcome

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, haven't had enough time.
The new desired output looks a bit more complicated. It seems that you need to add more logic and probably add more internal `for` loops in order to achieve that.